# Receiving error apr_socket_connect(): Invalid argument (22) when running apache bench (ab) on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, ab

I received the following error on Apache bench:

apr_socket_connect(): Invalid argument (22)

when trying to connect to http://localhost:9202.

Answer (score 54):

On OSX, the fix is to use "http://127.0.0.1" instead of localhost. Not sure why, but that prevents the error.

Comment: Using `127.0.0.1` also fixes this same issue on Window 7 64 bit pro, just tried it here. Thanks

Comment: I would guess it is because localhost resolves to the local IPv6 address, and the server you're trying to connect to only listens on IPv4. (Actually, I'll add that to your answer!)

Comment: localhost used to work for me, not sure why it stopped working. 127.0.0.1 resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: @kqr that's a great guess.  Is there a verbose option or something I could use to confirm that?  Maybe capture the request with `tcpdump`?

Comment: Confirmed by running `ab -n 1 -c 1 http://localhost/api/users/` and `sudo tcpdump ip6 and port 80 -i lo0 -X` simultaneously.  Thanks :)